# Change logical and physical file name when deploying dacpac

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

When deploying a dacpac for the first time using SqlPackage.exe how do I control the logical and physical file names for the new database.

The standard SQL statement would be:

```
CREATE DATABASE Bar
ON PRIMARY (NAME = 'Foo', FILENAME = '...\Foo\Foo.mdf')
LOG ON (NAME = 'Foo_log', FILENAME = '...\Foo\Foo.ldf')
```

Comment: could you give example please? I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is not possible out of the box with the current tools. The variables `$(DefaultFilePath)` and `$(DefaultLogPath)` control the location but cannot be changed from the command line.

These values can be changed by using a custom deployment contributor, see [Overriding DefaultDataPath and DefaultLogPath variables when using SqlPackage to publishing a dacpac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28912298/35233).